# Sum of previous rows values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

how I can sum previous rows values and current row value to a new column?
My current output:

```
index,value
0,1
1,2
2,3
3,4
4,5
```

My goal output is:

```
index,value,sum
0,1,1
1,2,3
2,3,6
3,4,10
4,5,15
```

I know that this is easy to do with Excel, but I'm looking solution to do with pandas.

My code:

```
import random, pandas

recordlist=[1,2,3,4,5]

df=pandas.DataFrame(recordlist, columns=["Values"])
```

Comment: do you have any example of code that we could look at?

Comment: @Astrom I edited the starting post.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

use [**`cumsum`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

```
df.assign(sum=df.value.cumsum())

       value  sum
index            
0          1    1
1          2    3
2          3    6
3          4   10
4          5   15
```

Or

```
df['sum'] = df.value.cumsum()
df

       value  sum
index            
0          1    1
1          2    3
2          3    6
3          4   10
4          5   15
```

If `df` is a series

```
pd.DataFrame(dict(value=df, sum=df.cumsum())
```

Comment: I get error message with this solution: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'value'.

Comment: @JuhoM covert your series to a dataframe with 'myseries.to_frame().assign(...)

Comment: @JuhoM I made the assumption that you had a dataframe. If it's a series, you can use PaulH's suggestion or see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

As already used in the previous posts, [df.assign](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) is a great function.

If you want to have a little bit more flexibility here, you can use a lambda function, like so

```py
df.assign[ sum=lambda l: l['index'] + l['value'] ]
```

Just to do the summing, this could even be shortened with

```py
df.assign[ sum=df['index'] + df['value'] ]
```

Note that `sum` (before the `=` sign) is not a function or variable, but the name for the new column. So this could be also `df.assign[ mylongersumlabel=.. ]`