# Making column that aggregates the values of another column w/ Python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Let sat I have a DataFrame with column A.

```
A= (1,2,3,4,5,6...n)
```

I want to create column B like this:

```
B=(1,3,6,10,15,21...n)
```

Explicitly: i+(sum of all the previous numbers)

Probably simple, but hard for me:P Very new to programming
Thanks!

Comment: `B = np.cumsum(A)` `import numpy as np`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sum of previous rows values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43396855/sum-of-previous-rows-values)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumsum as a new column in an existing Pandas data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41859311/cumsum-as-a-new-column-in-an-existing-pandas-data)

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import accumulate

A = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
B = list(accumulate(A)) #->[1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21]
```